# Android: How to use MediaStore to store all images' filepaths to a string array?

Tags: android

I am trying to find out how to use `MediaStore` and `managedQuery()` to get all the images on an android phone and store their filepaths to a string array. There's some information on google, but it is incomplete and I can't seem to get the code to work. If anyone could help me with this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I found it. It's `String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA };
        String selection = "";
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
     
  mImageExternalCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
  mImageInternalCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);` then `mImageExternalCursor.getString(mImageExternalCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA));` to retrieve the filepath.